# correct way to append data to a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, append, filewriter, printwriter

For this code, I want to simulate a slot machine and put the username and scores of the games onto a text file titled scores.txt so that if the user selects option 2 they can view their scores.

However, I receive many **errors on my FileWriter statement** (line is towards the end and marked with a comment), particulary one that I don't understand called unmappable character for encoding  CP1252. From everywhere I have checked, I see this error when someone uses a different character like a Japanese character- so why would an error like this come about? I've looked at examples of code but I have not yet learned stream, try and catch, or buffer.

**Using filewriter and printwriter** can someone explain to me how to create a filewriter object and pass it to a printwriter object correctly, as well as how to correctly read data from that file (scores.txt). Thanks so much in advance, and sorry if this is a simple error.

Specific area of problem:

```
File file = new File(“scores.txt”); //illegal start of expression

    if (!file.exists())
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    String line = inputReader.nextLine();
    FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(“scores.txt”, true); //this is where the error CP1252, 
    PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
    outputFile.println(username);
    outputFile.println(userFinalTotal);

}

else if (option == 2)
{
    if (file.exists())
    {   
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            username = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println ("Name\n------\n" + name + "\n");
            userFinaltotal = inputFile.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Scores\n------\n$%.2f\n", userFinalTotal);
            System.out.println();  
            inputReader.close();
        }
```

Here is the full program to see where the variables come from.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class SlotsMachine
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int number;

    System.out.println ("Welcome to the Slot Machine Simulator!");
    System.out.println ("\nActions\n1. Start a new game\n2. Scores\n3. Exit");
    System.out.print ("\nPlease select an action: ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (option != 1 && option != 2 && option != 3)
    {
    System.out.print ("\nThat is not an option. Please select an item number between 1-3: ");
    option = keyboard.nextInt();
    break;
    }

    if (option == 1)
    {
        String username; 
        double startingTotal = 100.0;
        double userTotal = startingTotal;

        System.out.print ("\nBefore the game begins, please enter your name: ");
        username = keyboard.next( );
        System.out.print ("\nGame start! You will begin with $100.00. Enter a negative value to quit the game. Good luck, " + username + "!");

        do
        {
            double bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
            bet = 0.0;
            userTotal = startingTotal - bet;

            System.out.print ("You currently have: " + startingTotal + "\nHow much would you like to bet?");

            double winnings = 0.0;
            double userFinalTotal = 0.0;

            if ((bet < 0) || (userFinalTotal <= 0))
            {
                break;
            }

            while (bet > userFinalTotal)
            {
                System.out.print("\nYour bet is greater than your current total. Please enter a valid amount: ");
                bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }

            Random generator = new Random();
            int slot1 = generator.nextInt(6);
            keyboard.nextLine();

            int slot2 = generator.nextInt(6);

            int slot3 = generator.nextInt(6);

            String firstSlot = "";

            switch (slot1)
            {
                case 0:
                    firstSlot = "Cherries";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    firstSlot = "Oranges";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    firstSlot = "Plums";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    firstSlot = "Bells";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    firstSlot = "Melons";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    firstSlot = "Bars";
                    break;
            }

            String secondSlot = "";

            switch (slot2)
            {
                case 0:
                    secondSlot = "Cherries";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    secondSlot = "Oranges";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    secondSlot = "Plums";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    secondSlot = "Bells";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    secondSlot = "Melons";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    secondSlot = "Bars";
                    break;
            }

            String thirdSlot = "";

            switch (slot3)
            {
                case 0:
                    thirdSlot = "Cherries";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    thirdSlot = "Oranges";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    thirdSlot = "Plums";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    thirdSlot = "Bells";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    thirdSlot = "Melons";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    thirdSlot = "Bars";
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println ("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println ("" + firstSlot + "    " + secondSlot + "    " + thirdSlot);
            System.out.print ("-------------------------------");

            if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3)
            {
                winnings = bet * 3;
                userFinalTotal = userTotal + winnings;
                System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 3. You win: $%.2f", winnings); 
                System.out.printf ("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", userFinalTotal);
            }
            else if ((slot1 == slot2 && slot2 != slot3) || (slot1 == slot3 && slot1 != slot2) || (slot2 == slot3 && slot3 != slot1))
            {   
                winnings = bet * 2;
                userFinalTotal = userTotal + winnings;
                System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 2. You win: $%.2f", winnings);
                System.out.printf ("\nYou currently have: $%.2fn", userFinalTotal);
            }   
            else
            {
                System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 0. You win: $%.2f", winnings);
                System.out.printf ("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", userFinalTotal);
            }       
        } while (userTotal > 0);

        File file = new File(“scores.txt”); //illegal start of expression

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        String line = inputReader.nextLine();
        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(“scores.txt”, true); //this is where the error CP1252
        PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
        outputFile.println(username);
        outputFile.println(userFinalTotal);

    }

    else if (option == 2)
    {
        if (file.exists())
        {   
            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                username = inputFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println ("Name\n------\n" + name + "\n");
                userFinaltotal = inputFile.nextDouble();
                System.out.printf("Scores\n------\n$%.2f\n", userFinalTotal);
                System.out.println();  
                inputReader.close();
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            System.out.println("There are no scores to display at this time.");
        }

        System.out.println("Actions:");
        System.out.print("1. Start a new game\n2. View scores\n3. Exit ");

        System.out.println("Please select an action: "); 
        option = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    else if (number == 3)
    {
        System.out.print ("\nGoodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please try to work through http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ – most people will not wade through such an absurdly long wad of code to find the needle in your haystack.  If you have isolated your problem, you will be able to much better express what’s your problem, and thus it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: @Vucar Timnärakrul Since it includes things from the code, I wanted to include the code so that one could see what variables needed to be included if that was an error. I placed a comment next to the line that had the error stating the error: unmappable character for encoding CP1252, along with illegal start of expression and saying I need a ; where the , is. I will try to add the specific section of code up at the top from now on, thanks for the input

Comment: @HedonicHedgehog I received an unmappable character for encoding CP1252 error, which from what I've been reading online seems to occur when someone uses different characters like Japanese characters. I don't know how that would come here. Also, on that line there is an error saying there should be a ; where the comma is and illegal start of expression. The line is commented on the code.

Comment: Did you copy that file name? It looks like you're using directed quotes which the java compiler does not like. Replace with undirected ""

Comment: @HedonicHedgehog I rewrote the filename and that fixed the CP1252 error, but now there seems to be some other problems finding inputFile and file. Thank you for helping with the CP1252 error, I didn't even realize that.

Comment: There are a large number of errors that can result from any operation. Being vague helps no one. You need to specify the exact exception thrown or show the stack trace of the error.

If I had to guess, I assume your error is a path error. You should try passing the full path to your file as the string. Currently I believe it is looking for the file at C:\scores.txt whereas you probably have the file saved in the current directory.

There is a way to open files in same directory as the class file, but i don't remember it offhand. A quick stack overflow search should find it for you.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be vague, I just meant I was going to try to figure out the other error. I posted my correction as an answer.

Comment: What I meant was this:  If you cut back the ‘fat’ of your code and leave out *everything* that’s not strictly related to the error, you will get a clearer picture as to what’s actually wrong (and thus can clarify your question), and more often than not the answer’ll jump at you in the process.  It’s the most important thing that you **have** to learn when you want to become a programmer.  I’ll try to be of more direct help once I have some more free time. ^^

Answer (score 0):

It compiles now, the only problem is that it prints the scores multiple times.
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.io.*;

```
public class Slot3
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println ("Welcome to the Slot Machine Simulator!");

    int option = 0;

    //if the user selects a 1 or 2 (does not want to exit) then this loop will run
    do
    {
        System.out.println ("\nActions\n1. Start a new game\n2. Scores\n3. Exit");
        System.out.print ("\nPlease select an action: ");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        option = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        while (option != 1 && option != 2 && option != 3)
        {
            System.out.print ("\nThat is not an option. Please select an item number between 1-3: ");
            option = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }

        //this will occur if the user selects 1 to play the game
        if (option == 1)
        {
            double money = 100.00;
            double bet = 0.00;
            double winnings = 0.00;
            double score = 0.00;
            int count = 0;

            System.out.print ("\nBefore the game begins, please enter your name: ");
            String username = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print ("\nGame start! You will begin with $100.00. Enter a negative value to quit the game. Good luck, " + username + "!");

            System.out.printf("\nYou currently have $%.2f.", 100.00);

            do 
            {
                System.out.printf("\n\nHow much would you like to bet? ");
                bet = keyboard.nextDouble();

                if ((bet < 0) || (money <= 0))
                {
                    break;
                }

                while (bet > money)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nYour bet is greater than your current total. Please enter a valid amount: ");
                    bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
                }

                //create random numbers
                Random generator = new Random();
                int slot1 = generator.nextInt(6);

                int slot2 = generator.nextInt(6);

                int slot3 = generator.nextInt(6);

                String firstSlot = "";

                switch (slot1)
                {
                    case 0:
                        firstSlot = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        firstSlot = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        firstSlot = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        firstSlot = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        firstSlot = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        firstSlot = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                String secondSlot = "";

                switch (slot2)
                {
                    case 0:
                        secondSlot = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        secondSlot = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        secondSlot = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        secondSlot = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        secondSlot = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        secondSlot = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                String thirdSlot = "";

                switch (slot3)
                {
                    case 0:
                        thirdSlot = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        thirdSlot = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        thirdSlot = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        thirdSlot = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        thirdSlot = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        thirdSlot = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                System.out.println ("\n-------------------------------");
                System.out.printf ("%-12s%-10s%5s\n", firstSlot , secondSlot , thirdSlot);
                System.out.print ("\n-------------------------------");

                //check how many of the slots match to calculate the winnings
                if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3)
                {
                    winnings = bet * 3;
                    money -= bet;
                    score = money + winnings;
                    System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 3. You win: $%.2f", winnings); 
                     System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", score);
                }
                else if ((slot1 == slot2 && slot2 != slot3) || (slot1 == slot3 && slot1 != slot2) || (slot2 == slot3 && slot3 != slot1))
                {   
                    winnings = bet * 2;
                    money -= bet;
                    score = money + winnings;
                    System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 2. You win: $%.2f", winnings);
                    System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", score);
                }   
                else
                {
                    winnings = bet * 0;
                    money -= bet;
                    score = money + winnings;
                    System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 0. You win: $%.2f", winnings);
                    System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", score);
                }     
            } while ((bet > 0) && (money > 0)); 

            FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("scores.txt", true);
            PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
            outputWriter.printf("\n\n%1s%15s" , "Name" , "Score");
            outputWriter.printf ("\n\n%1s%15s" , "----" , "-----");
            outputWriter.printf ("\n\n%1s%15s" , username , score);
            outputWriter.close();

            System.out.println("\n\nGame over! Your score has been written to scores.txt, " + username + "!");

        } //end of actions for select option 1

        //option 2 user wants to read their scores
        if (option == 2)
        {
            File myFile = new File("scores.txt");

            //if there are no scores to read
            if (!myFile.exists())
            {   
                System.out.println("There are no scores to display at this time.");
                continue;
            }

            File file = new File("scores.txt");

            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                String username = inputFile.nextLine(); 

                System.out.println(username);
            }
            inputFile.close();
        } //close option 2
    } while (option != 3); //close 1st do-while loop

    if (option == 3)
    {
        System.out.print ("\nGoodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    } 
}
```

}